# Where is Border component in Flex/mx library?

Tags: apache-flex, halo, flex-mx

I have an old Flex app build with the Halo library.  Now that Halo was changed to mx library, it makes the old Border component stop working and I'm unable to build the project anymore.

Even when I try to change the library to MX, the Border cannot build.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Programmatic Skin [Border](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/skins/Border.html) class?  The class is in the same location in my Flex 4 source that it is in in my Flex 3 source.  They may have changed it's namespace location, but it seems unlikely.  Perhaps if you share some code with us?

Comment: yes, it is Programmatic Skin Border class. At first, it displays that halo could not resolve. After I change from halo to mx, other error display at the line of code:
<s:Border id="subMenuBorder" borderAlpha="1" borderColor="#333333" height="73"  >
Then if I remove ID attribute, the error move to other file... I dont understand at all

Comment: You're going to have show some code full code and I suggest editing your original question.  If you're using MXML, then i suspect the problem is with namespaces (AKA: mx, s, fx ) and not with package names.  Really "halo" was always called MX.